# Function for an encryption program

Tags: python, encryption

I am having a bit of an issue with this code. This code is for a school assignment. Basically I need to make a program that works with ceaser cipher encryption and I've managed to make a basic one. The only problem is that when entering any form of text, the ciphertext is printing [] only. When putting it in the function it says 'not defined.' (All I am asking is for help on this specific bit not for someone to finish my project. PS it has to be in a function) Thanks in advance.

```
userentry = input("Enter Text: ")
ciphertext = []
ceaseralpha = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j','k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', ' ']
plaintext = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j','k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ' ']


def encrypt(plaintext):

   for sentence in userentry:
      for char in sentence:
         ciphertext.append(ceaseralpha[plaintext.index(char)])

print(ciphertext)

encrypt(plaintext)
```

> >Enter Text: a
> >[]

Comment: Try printing the ciphertext after doing the encryption.

Comment: yep it worked. Thnx so much Artjom <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is all mixed up.

Here, let me straighten it out for you:

```py
ceaseralpha = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j','k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', ' ']
plaintext = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j','k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ' ']


def encrypt(userentry):
    ciphertext = []
    for char in userentry:
         ciphertext.append(ceaseralpha[plaintext.index(char)])
    return ciphertext

userentry = input("Enter Text: ")
ciphertext = encrypt(userentry)
print(ciphertext)
```